# How to make a generic request service in Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

i've created an generic request service but it keeps returning 'ZoneAwarePromise'. I've tried to use .pipe() and .subscribe() to try to retrive the content of the request, but it's not working.

requester.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequesterService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  request(method, url, headers, body, params) {
    return this.http.request(method, url, {
      body: body || {},
      headers: headers || {},
      params: params || {}
    })
  }

  async get(url, params?, headers?, data?) {
    return await this.request('get', url, params, headers, data)
  }

  async post(url, params, headers, data) {
    return await this.request('post', url, params, headers, data);
  }

  async put(url, params, headers, data) {
    return await this.request('put', url, params, headers, data);
  }

  async delete(url, params, headers, data) {
    return await this.request('delete', url, params, headers, data);
  }
}
```

gym-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RequesterService } from 'src/app/core/Requester/requester.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gym-list',
  templateUrl: './gym-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gym-list.component.css']
})
export class GymListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Requester: RequesterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.teste())
  }

  async teste() {
    await this.Requester.get('https://searchs.glitch.me/proposalcontent')
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the logic without the `async` and `await` in your `RequesterService`?  I haven't ever used those with an Observable, so those would be my first thought as to what might be fubaring the attempted usage of pipe and subscribe.

Comment: How is `Requester.get(url, ...)` any easier than `http.get(url, ...)`?

Comment: there is no wrong of using async/await you jest have to convert an observable to promise and observable has a method for this , check m answer ifit work for 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return an non-async function with await.

```
  request(method, url, headers, body, params) {
    return this.http.request(method, url, {
      body: body || {},
      headers: headers || {},
      params: params || {}
    })
  }

  async get(url, params?, headers?, data?) {
    return await this.request('get', url, params, headers, data)
  }
```

You shouldn't use async-await system here.

Try this:

```
  get(url, params?, headers?, data?) {
    return this.request('get', url, params, headers, data)
  }
```

And subscribe this method in your component.ts file.

Like this:

```
Requester.get.subscribe(....)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpEventType, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { IGenericHttpClient } from './igeneric-http-client';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpMethod } from '../view-models/component-type.enum'
import { IRequestOptions } from '../view-models/interface';
import { EnvironmentViewModel } from '../view-models/environment-view-model';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class GenericHttpClient<T> implements IGenericHttpClient<T>{

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private environment: EnvironmentViewModel) { }

  public Post(destinationUrl: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.request<T>(HttpMethod.Post, destinationUrl, options);
  }

  public Put(destinationUrl: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.request<T>(HttpMethod.Put, destinationUrl, options);
  }

  public Get(destinationUrl: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.request<T>(HttpMethod.Get, destinationUrl, options);
  }

  public Delete(destinationUrl: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.request<T>(HttpMethod.Delete, destinationUrl, options);
  }

  private request<T>(method: string, url: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
    return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
      this.httpClient.request<T>(new HttpRequest(method, this.environment.baseUrl + url, options)).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          const responsTye = response as HttpEvent<any>
          switch (responsTye.type) {
            case HttpEventType.Sent:
              console.log('Request sent!');
              break;
            case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
              console.log('Response header received!');
              break;
            case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
              const kbLoaded = Math.round(responsTye.loaded / 1024);
              console.log(`Download in progress! ${kbLoaded}Kb loaded`);
              break;
            case HttpEventType.Response:
              observer.next(response.body);
              console.log(' Done!', responsTye.body);
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          switch (error.status) {
            case 403:
              observer.complete();
              break;
            default:
              observer.error(error);
              break;
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can create an abstract base service class that can be extended in any service. This will automatically handle the error by calling another service that has a generic error handling code. If you pass `customError` flag the error will be returned into the component for handing custom error. This method is using `RxJs` `Observables` which can be subscribed in component.ts and catch the response and error.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

import { HttpOptionsService } from "../../services/httpoptions.service";

export abstract class ServiceBase {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private httpOptionService: HttpOptionsService
  ) {}

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })
  };

  getFormattedPostRequest(
    url: string,
    body: any,
    customError: boolean = false): Observable<any> {
    return this.pipeTapObservable(
      this.http.post(url, body, this.httpOptions),
      customError
    );
  }

  getFormattedPutRequest(
    url: string,
    body: any,
    customError: boolean = false
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.pipeTapObservable(
      this.http.put(url, body, this.httpOptions),
      customError
    );
  }

  getFormattedGetRequest(
    url: string,
    customError: boolean = false
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.pipeTapObservable(
      this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions),
      customError
    );
  }

  getFormattedDeleteRequest(
    url: string,
    customError: boolean = false
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.pipeTapObservable(
      this.http.delete(url, this.httpOptions),
      customError
    );
  }

  private pipeTapObservable(
    request: Observable<any>,
    customError: boolean = false
  ): Observable<any> {
    return request.pipe(
      tap(
        response => response,
        error => {
          !customError &&
            this.httpOptionService.handleError(error);
          return error;
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

If you have some common headers to be added you can create an interceptor to add them. You can use it in any service like below.

```
 @Injectable()
    export class MyService extends ServiceBase {
      constructor(
        http: HttpClient,
        httpOptionService: HttpOptionsService
    ) {
        super(http, httpOptionService);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use async/await but this syntax work on promise type and request method return an observable so you just need to return a promise from request method or you can do it on the return statement on the get,post,put,delete method

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequesterService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  request(method, url, headers, body, params) {
    return this.http.request(method, url, {
      body: body || {},
      headers: headers || {},
      params: params || {}
    }).toPromise();
  }

   get(url, params?, headers?, data?) {
    return this.request('get', url, params, headers, data);
  }

   post(url, params, headers, data) {
    return this.request('post', url, params, headers, data);
  }

   put(url, params, headers, data) {
    return this.request('put', url, params, headers, data);
  }

   delete(url, params, headers, data) {
    return this.request('delete', url, params, headers, data);
  }
}
```

*component*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RequesterService } from 'src/app/core/Requester/requester.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gym-list',
  templateUrl: './gym-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gym-list.component.css']
})
export class GymListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Requester: RequesterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.teste())
  }

  async teste() {
    const result = await this.Requester.get('https://searchs.glitch.me/proposalcontent');

    console.log(result); 
  }
}
```